# Pendo Guide Poll - How to create a multi-Select polls with checkbox’s

Tags: javascript, html, pendo

I want to be able to create a multiple checkbox poll for the first step (STEP 1) of the "pendo guide" and a radio button poll for the next step (STEP 2)

Here some question examples from the poll:

STEP 1

[Q is required to answer to move to step 2]

Q: Which communication or collaboration software do you use? [select all that apply]

((The user would be able to select multiple options from the list below))

- Slack

- Google Chat

- Microsoft Teams

- Zoom

- None of the above

STEP 2

[Q is required to answer to move to submit the poll]

Q: How much time daily are you on your mobile? [select one]

((The user would be able to select only 1 option from the list below))

- 2-4 hours

- 4-6 hours

- 6-9 hours

- 9-12 hours

- 12-16 hours

----------------

Thanks for your help!

`I was triying to edit the code in html [Pendo Guide - Edit Code ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW1GQ.png)`

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Multi-Select Checkbox Poll</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.pendo.io/agent/static/<YOUR_PENDO_TRACKING_ID>/pendo.js"></script>
  <style>
    .pollContainer {
      font-size: 14px;
        color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
      font-weight: 400;
      position: relative;
      float: none;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      margin: 0px 0px 8px;
      padding: 0px;
      font-size: 13px;
      letter-spacing: 0px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
      text-transform: none;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: left;
    }

    h2, h3 {
      color: rgb(83, 82, 82);   
      font-weight: 200;
      position: relative;
      float: none;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      margin: 0px 0px 8px;
      padding: 0px;
      font-size: 14px;
      letter-spacing: 0px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
      text-transform: none;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: left;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"], button {
      font-size: 14px;
    } 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    
  <div class="pollContainer" id="question1Container">
    <h3>1. Which communication or collaboration software do you use? ? Select all that apply.</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Slack" required>Slack<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Google Chat" required>Google Chat<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Microsoft Teams" required>Microsoft Teams<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Zoom" required>ZoomTeams<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="None of the above" required>None of the above<br>
  </div>


  <div class="pollContainer" id="question3Container">
    <h3>3. How much time daily are you on your mobile? select one.</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="2-4 hours" required>2-4 hours<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="4-6 hours" required>4-6 hours t<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="6-9 hours" required>6-9 hours<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="9-12 hours" required>9-12 hours<br>  
  </div>
```

here is the Javascript:

```
var requiredQuestions = [];
var requiredPollIds = [];
var dependentButtons = [];
var textForDisabledButtons = ["Submit", "Next", "Finish"];
var isButtonDisabled = false;

function requiredHTML(dataPendoPollId) {
    return '<div class="required-wrapper" name="' +  dataPendoPollId + '">* Required</div>'; 
} 

function disableEligibleButtons(textForDisabledButtons) {
    for(var i=0; i < textForDisabledButtons.length; i++) {
        var eligibleButtons = pendo.dom("._pendo-button:contains('" + textForDisabledButtons[i] + "')");
        for (var k=0; k < eligibleButtons.length; k++) {
            eligibleButtons[k].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}

function enableEligibleButtons(textForDisabledButtons) {
    for(var i=0; i < textForDisabledButtons.length; i++) {
        var eligibleButtons = pendo.dom("._pendo-button:contains('" + textForDisabledButtons[i] + "')");
        for (var k=0; k < eligibleButtons.length; k++) {
            eligibleButtons[k].disabled = false;
        }
    }
}

if(!pendo.designerEnabled) {
    function processRequiredQuestions() {
        requiredQuestions = pendo.dom("._pendo-open-text-poll-question:contains('[REQUIRED]'), ._pendo-number-scale-poll-question:contains('[REQUIRED]'), ._pendo-multi-choice-poll-question:contains('[REQUIRED]')");
        for(i=0; i<requiredQuestions.length; i++) {
            var dataPendoPollId = requiredQuestions[i].getAttribute("data-pendo-poll-id");
            requiredPollIds.push(dataPendoPollId);
            if(pendo.dom("._pendo-multi-choice-poll-select-border[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredPollIds[i] + "']")[0]) {
                pendo.dom("._pendo-multi-choice-poll-select-border[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredPollIds[i] + "']")[0].parentElement.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', requiredHTML(dataPendoPollId));
            } else {
                pendo.dom(".pendo-block-wrapper[data-pendo-poll-id='" + dataPendoPollId + "']")[0].parentElement.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', requiredHTML(dataPendoPollId));
            }
            requiredQuestions[i].innerHTML = requiredQuestions[i].innerHTML.replace("[REQUIRED]", "");
        }
        if(requiredPollIds.length>0) {
            disableEligibleButtons(textForDisabledButtons);
        }
    }

    function evaluateRequiredQuestions() {
        var allRequiredComplete = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < requiredPollIds.length; i++) {
            if (pendo.dom("._pendo-open-text-poll-wrapper[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredPollIds[i] + "']")[0]) {
                if(pendo.dom("._pendo-open-text-poll-wrapper[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredPollIds[i] + "'] textarea")[0].value == "") {
                    var allRequiredComplete = false;
                }
            }
            if (pendo.dom("._pendo-number-scale-poll-wrapper[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredPollIds[i] + "']")[0]) {
                if(!(pendo.dom("._pendo-number-scale-poll-wrapper[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredPollIds[i] + "']")[0].querySelector(':checked'))) {
                    var allRequiredComplete = false;
                }
            }
            if (pendo.dom("._pendo-multi-choice-poll-select-border[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredPollIds[i] + "']")[0]) {
                if(!(pendo.dom("._pendo-multi-choice-poll-select-border[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredPollIds[i] + "']")[0].querySelector(':checked'))) {
                    var allRequiredComplete = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (allRequiredComplete) {
            enableEligibleButtons(textForDisabledButtons);
        } else {
            disableEligibleButtons(textForDisabledButtons);
        }
    }

    processRequiredQuestions();

    document.querySelectorAll("._pendo-open-text-poll-input").forEach(textbox => {
        textbox.addEventListener("input", function() {
            evaluateRequiredQuestions();
        })
    })

    pendo.dom("#pendo-guide-container")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(!event.target.classList.contains("_pendo-button")) {
           evaluateRequiredQuestions(); 
        }
    });

}

if(pendo.designerEnabled) {                          
    addRequiredMutationListener = function() {
        var target = document.querySelector('#pendo-guide-container');

        // create an observer instance
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
                    // Add requiredToggle if new Open Text Poll is added
                    if(mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelector("._pendo-open-text-poll-wrapper, ._pendo-number-scale-poll-wrapper, ._pendo-multi-choice-poll-select-border")) {
                        var dataPendoPollId = "";
                        if(mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelector("._pendo-open-text-poll-wrapper, ._pendo-number-scale-poll-wrapper")) {
                            var dataPendoPollId = mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelector("form").getAttribute("name");
                        } else {
                            var dataPendoPollId = mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelector("._pendo-multi-choice-poll-select-border").getAttribute("data-pendo-poll-id");
                        }

                        var questionText = "";
                        if(pendo.dom("._pendo-open-text-poll-question[data-pendo-poll-id=" + dataPendoPollId + "]")[0]) {
                            questionText = pendo.dom("._pendo-open-text-poll-question[data-pendo-poll-id=" + dataPendoPollId + "]")[0].textContent;
                        }
                        if(pendo.dom("._pendo-number-scale-poll-question[data-pendo-poll-id=" + dataPendoPollId + "]")[0]) {
                            questionText = pendo.dom("._pendo-number-scale-poll-question[data-pendo-poll-id=" + dataPendoPollId + "]")[0].textContent;
                        }
                        if(pendo.dom("._pendo-multi-choice-poll-question[data-pendo-poll-id=" + dataPendoPollId + "]")[0]) {
                            questionText = pendo.dom("._pendo-multi-choice-poll-question[data-pendo-poll-id=" + dataPendoPollId + "]")[0].textContent;
                        }                           
                        

                        if(questionText.includes("[REQUIRED]")){
                            mutation.addedNodes[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', requiredHTML(dataPendoPollId));
                            if(requiredQuestions.includes(dataPendoPollId)) {
                                var index = requiredQuestions.indexOf(dataPendoPollId);
                                if (index !== -1) {
                                    requiredQuestions.splice(index, 1);
                                }
                            } else {
                                requiredQuestions.push(dataPendoPollId);
                            }
                            
                        } else {
                            if(requiredQuestions.includes(dataPendoPollId)) {
                                var index = requiredQuestions.indexOf(dataPendoPollId);
                                if (index !== -1) {
                                requiredQuestions.splice(index, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var allRequiredComplete = true;
                    for(var i = 0; i < requiredQuestions.length; i++) {
                        if (pendo.dom("._pendo-open-text-poll-wrapper[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredQuestions[i] + "']")[0]) {
                            if(pendo.dom("._pendo-open-text-poll-wrapper[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredQuestions[i] + "'] textarea")[0].value == "") {
                                var allRequiredComplete = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (pendo.dom("._pendo-number-scale-poll-wrapper[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredQuestions[i] + "']")[0]) {
                            if(!(pendo.dom("._pendo-number-scale-poll-wrapper[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredQuestions[i] + "']")[0].querySelector(':checked'))) {
                                var allRequiredComplete = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (pendo.dom("._pendo-multi-choice-poll-select-border[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredQuestions[i] + "']")[0]) {
                            if(!(pendo.dom("._pendo-multi-choice-poll-select-border[data-pendo-poll-id='" + requiredQuestions[i] + "']")[0].querySelector(':checked'))) {
                                var allRequiredComplete = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (allRequiredComplete) {
                        enableEligibleButtons(textForDisabledButtons);
                    } else {
                        disableEligibleButtons(textForDisabledButtons);
                    }
                }
            })
        });
                

        var config = {
            attributeFilter: ['data-layout'],
            attributes: true,
            childList: true,
            characterData: true,
            subtree: false
        };

        observer.observe(target, config);
    }

    addRequiredMutationListener();
}
```